# Increasing my navbar size/height throws off my bootstrap full height columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make my bootstrap navbar bigger (bigger buttons, bigger input, height, etc) but after I make the 1st element large (input -> input-lg) in the navbar it ruins my 2 columns that are full height. It creates an outer scroll on the page that I don't want.
I have this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/73u9xTGDew) here that has a navbar and 2 columns that are 100% height and you can see the outer scroll bar created because of the large input in the navbar. If I remove the large input from the navbar the navbar shrinks and the columns resize back to full height and the outer scroll goes away.

Question - is there a good plugin or library for bootstrap navbars that will let me make them bigger then the standard size and customize them?

Here is my code

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}
.table-container {
  height: calc(100% - 53px);
  /*border: 1px solid green;*/
}
nav.navbar {
  margin: 0;
}
.table-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.table-container .table-row {
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.table-container .table-row .table-col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
}
#eventsContainer,
#hostsContainer,
#teachersContainer {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
.table-row {
  margin: 0;
}
.resultBtn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search" type="text">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container table-container">
  <div class="row table-row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 table-col">nav</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 table-col" style="border: 1px solid red;">
      <div id="eventsContainer">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update your snippet to be a real working example (include all the js/css/required files for it to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the change of your input, your `.navbar` has a `min-height` of 50px, and the `.table-container`'s height was `calc(100% - 53px);` (which was good, and caused your `<body>` element to have no scroll.

Now that your input is larger (in the `.navbar`) - the `height` of the navbar is actually `64px`, and if you use `calc(100% - 53px)` it's not enough, and you will have a scrollbar on your `<body>` element.

If you have that height to be `calc(100% - 64px);` it will remove your scrollbar:

http://www.bootply.com/iX3kL0vmNW